# Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed. This query has a prefix, variable, or user-defined function. in HTMLAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I have following contents in Html Document

```
 <opf:metadata xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:opf="http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf">
    <dc:title>Book Title</dc:title>
    <dc:language>en-us</dc:language>
    <meta name="cover" content="My_Cover" xmlns="" />
    <dc:identifier id="BookId" opf:scheme="ISBN">123456789</dc:identifier>
    <dc:creator>Author Name</dc:creator>
    <dc:publisher>amazon.com</dc:publisher>
    <dc:subject>amazon.com</dc:subject>
    <dc:date>2014-02-28T00:00:00+05:30</dc:date>
  </opf:metadata>
```

I have to change the value of `<dc:date>` attribute's value to current date. I am using HtmlAgilityPack and the code as below

```
var html1 = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
             html1.LoadHtml(OPFFile);

             var links1 = html1.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("opf:metadata");

             foreach (var link in links1)
             {

                 link.Attributes["dc:date"].Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
             }

             var builder1 = new StringBuilder();
             using (var writer = new StringWriter(builder))
             {
                 html1.Save(writer);
             }
             OPFFile = builder1.ToString();
             File.WriteAllText(@"D:\FindImageInFile\FindImageInFile\OPF.html", OPFFile);
```

But when i tried to convert i am getting this error `Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed. This query has a prefix, variable, or user-defined function.`
How to change its value ?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that [HtmlAgilityPack doesn't support XPath containing prefix](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/discussions/211321).

If your html document is well-formed (valid xml), you can use [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), both support namespace/prefix.

For example, to get `<cd:date>` element from sample xml above using `XDocument` :

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(OPFFile);
//or if OPFFile is file path use : XDocument.Load(OPFFile);
XNamespace dc = "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/";
var date = (string)xdoc.Root.Element(dc + "date");
```

Comment: i am not using LINQ. i am just working on simple windows application.

Comment: yes, that's a good reason not to use 3rd party library (if possible). Anyway, I don't find a way to use prefix with HAP so far.